# How do i keep track of which tag does what in an analytics tool

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, flurry, mixpanel, amplitude-analytics

Analytic tagging service like Google Analytics, Firebase Analytics, Amplitude, MixPanel, Flurry etc all requires you to map a tag name to an action in your application like a button click or a page view.

For a small application, it is easy to keep track of the tag as in you would know which tag does what in which page. But in a huge application where you have hundreds of tags, it is hard to keep track of which tag does what.

The result is stakeholders regularly asks the developer to trace back to that particular action and provide them with the tag name.

For a non-technical person (without debugging or looking at the code), how does one knows which tag does what in which page? Is there any tools to help keep track of the tags?

Answer (score 0):

You need Tag Management System, for example, Google Tag Manager.

Comment: I believe tag manager service like Google Tag Manager, TealiumIQ, Adobe Dynamic Tag Management and etc helps you redistribute your tags to multiple collectors as well as a slew of other tools to manage your tags. However i do not see anything in those tools that can help me answer the question of "In this particular page, this button, what is it tag as". Correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: @WKL Tag Management Systems allow you to see what tags are on site/app and by what rules (triggers) they work. GTM, for example, have debugging tool (preview mode), so you can interact with particular page/screen and see what tags fires. The great tool is GA Debugger from keithclark (https://keithclark.github.io/gadebugger/). But it seems for web sites only.

Comment: @WKL Sorry, preview mode in GTM don't work with mobile apps https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en.